Remix: how to set input of type file dynamically
is there a way to do something like this.
const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
const [preview, setPreview] = useState<string | null>(null);
const onUpload = (file: File) => {
        setFile(file);
          if (file) {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = () => setPreview(reader.result as string);
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
         }
      <input name="file" type="file" value={file} />
};

The preview is showing and i get this error meassge:

This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
Nb; I am using a drag and drop component to get the files.

this worked but it's not what i want
<input name="file" type="file" />

